# Storing waves info in waves-based game

Tags: c#, database, xna

Me and my friend are relatively new to Game Programming, although we are pretty good with XNA basics. We started developing a wave-based defense game. The problem is that, the way I see it, it looks like a bad idea to hardcode the lists of enemies containing how many enemies of each type come each wave. Is there a better solution and what is it? Maybe we need a database? If this is the case, please recommend one.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a bit too broad to answer, and would also fit better on another Stack Exchange site as you're in the design phase as opposed to the implementation phase. You can of course simply start with a text file containing the waves and the enemies they contain.

Comment: I think it's too broad. I think you are the best guy to anwer your own question. However, I am working on a same type of game, and I just use formula's with some if statements based on the wave.
for example: `enemysToSpawn[<insert some sort of identifier of the enemy here>] = wave * 2 + 1;`

Comment: Depending on the game wave generation can be static (formulas as @joppiesaus suggestion, database *wave definion*, etc.) or *procedural*. Last one includes randomness (a little bit more of certain enemy, a little bit different time to spawn, etc) and generally is better for a *game* (unless your game required to learn exact types of enemies and what to build to win that wave). It is one of *balancing* issue, as making it too easy will make game boring, too hard - impossible of un-enjoyable. In any case consider to use difficulty setting in the game and balancing `Hard` to be barely doable.

Comment: What I mean is what you can start with the simple arrays (or lists) and later (when balancing) move it into database or game resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store this information in a variety of ways.  The simplest is to have a dedicated C# file with the information.  More complicated would be to have a Text document that you can read in.  Even more complicated is having an XML, CSV, or JSON file that you read in at runtime.

Keep in mind that the representation of data can be performed just as well in code as in a more "traditional" data format like XML - so it comes down to questions like who will be maintaining the data (are they more comfortable using XML over C#?), what kind of data pipeline you already have in place (are you using or are you familiar with libraries that can read in formats like json or xml?), and do you need data to be dynamically changed after the game has been launched (you can't change C# on a compiled game, but you can change the XML it loads).